# Adding an empty dynamic layer makes my shapefiles display correctly - without it they are incorrect

Tags: arcgis-engine

I have a completely empty dynamic layer

```
public class CustDynamicLayer2 : BaseDynamicLayer
{
public override void DrawDynamicLayer(esriDynamicDrawPhase DynamicDrawPhase, IDisplay iDisplay, IDynamicDisplay iDynamicDisplay) { }
}
```

I add a shape file with these four calls:

```
gcs = srFactory.CreateGeographicCoordinateSystem((int)esriSRGeoCSType.esriSRGeoCS_WGS1984);
mapControl.SpatialReference = gcs; 
mapControl.Map.AddLayer(new CustDynamicLayer2()); //without this my shapefile is badly distorted
mapControl.AddShapeFile(fileDir, fileName);
```

Basically if I don't add that empty class CustDynamicLayer2, the shapefile is distorted.  This makes no sense to me because the class doesn't do anything.

Comment: Sounds like a projection issue. Is the shapefile projected to a different coordinate system than you're used to using?

Comment: @Michael Todd, I looked into that.  I tried it with the same projection as the shapefile, esriSRGeoCS_NAD1983HARN, and got the same results

Comment: Are your geometries simple/valid (outer rings counter-clockwise, inner rings clockwise)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem went away, now if I load the shapefile its distorted, but if I hit full extent it readjusts itself.  So I think the drawing got interrupted or something.